# matcher association list lisp

Tags: lisp, matcher

Hi everyone I am new to programming and I have to work with association list like this

```
((course (john .math) (jim .english) (carl .biology) )
 (year (john .2) (jim. 1) (carl .3))
 (age (john .22) (jim .20) (carl .27))
)
```

I am supposed to use the matcher  to work like that with a function lookup

```
(lookup 'john 'course data) and return math
```

Now I am new to programming and completely new to Lisp and need to do this for the school. Now  I do not need a complete solution necessary but some ideas or instructions.

This is what I have though so far but took me a lot of time

If someone can help it will be much appreciated!!!!

```
(defun lookup (name course data)

(matches '(name course data) '(first course  )) 

)
```

Comment: Take several hours to read a Lisp (or a Scheme) programming book. We can't teach you it in a few minutes. If you are learning Scheme, [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) is a must read (and IIRC, partly answers your question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let's put the data into a list called `data`. Pay attention that the list needs to be [quoted](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_quote.htm) by `'`, and that the [`.` dot signs](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_cc.htm) need to be surrounded by spaces because they have a signification of their own:

```
(defparameter *data* '((course (john . math) (jim . english) (carl . biology))
                       (year   (john . 2)    (jim . 1)       (carl . 3))
                       (age    (john . 22)   (jim . 20)      (carl . 27))))
```

Now let's try using procedure [`assoc`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_assocc.htm):

```
? *data*
((COURSE (JOHN . MATH) (JIM . ENGLISH) (CARL . BIOLOGY)) (YEAR (JOHN . 2) (JIM . 1) (CARL . 3)) (AGE (JOHN . 22) (JIM . 20) (CARL . 27)))
? (assoc 'course *data*)
(COURSE (JOHN . MATH) (JIM . ENGLISH) (CARL . BIOLOGY))
? (cdr (assoc 'course *data*))
((JOHN . MATH) (JIM . ENGLISH) (CARL . BIOLOGY))
? (assoc 'john (cdr (assoc 'course *data*)))
(JOHN . MATH)
? (cdr (assoc 'john (cdr (assoc 'course *data*))))
MATH
```

so the function becomes

```
(defun lookup (name attr data)
  (cdr (assoc name (cdr (assoc attr data)))))

(lookup 'john 'course *data*) 
=> MATH

(lookup 'carl 'age *data*) 
=> 27
```

Comment: You're welcome. And no, Luxembourg is not Germany (although we learn German at school) ;-)

Comment: I am aware that Luxembourg is not in Germany but I though the official language is German, like in Belgium is French :))  Thanks again

Comment: Please use `*data*` as the global variable - not `data`. In your example `data` is now declared special and thus in the function `LOOKUP` the parameter `data` uses dynamic binding (!). This may not matter here, but it's best to get used to this style early.